# How to make a real-time jquery effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to make a real-time feed reader, and i want a solution to make the new items coming without refreshing the page and with a scrolling effect like friendfeed.

you can see what i'm talking about here: http://www.vimeo.com/4029954

I just want a function which i can call with new DIV content and then it create it above the previous DIVs with the effect.

Note: i already have the ajax and settimeout functions, means that i have the new feeds content to be added, so what i'm looking for is the effect and function to add new divs with scrolling effect!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for something better than the `slideDown()` effect. That isn't quite right as it just increases the height of an object rather than making it appear to "scroll" into view. Check out the `show()` effects from jQuery UI. http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/#option-effect I imagine the "Slide" effect would be appropriate if you gave it the option to slide vertically. The "Drop" effect sounds like it would be right, but I get the same effect as "slide" when I try it. Perhaps that is a bug in the demo site at the moment.

You may also be interested in using the `animate()` method to animate the `top` property of an element so that you can 'scroll' it into view. You'd need to have a container with `overflow: hidden` and a set `height` and `width` with `position: relative` set. Then, an inner container with `position: absolute` which you can then animate the `top` property of with `jQuery.animate()`.

```
var $items = $("#scroller .inner *");
$('#scroller .inner').animate({
    top: '-' + Math.round( $items.length * $items.eq(0).outerHeight(true) ) + 'px'
  });
```

Note that if you know how many pixels tall each inner element would be, you could replace the `$items.eq(0).outerHeight(true)` with the integer value of the known height.

Comment: I don't get your comment that slideDown just increases the height instead of making it appear.Actually it does exactly that. When you have a div with display: none property it "slides it down" up to the moment it's completely visible.

Comment: Added use case for `jQuery.animate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As you want the function that you call with new DIV content then I assume that you already did AJAX request.

Then to add the content to the site:
If you are matching the container of all entries then you'll need http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend#content, 
if you're matching the first entry you'll use http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before#content.

If you want nice slide down effect just use ... wait-for-it ... yes, slide down function :) http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown

Answer (score 0):

Here are some techniques which can help you further, but you should do the research yourself after this:

- **Comet** for streaming data over a persistent HTTP connection. Quite real-time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))
- **AJAX Polling** sending a request to a HTTP, which is also a persistent connection, but closes after data is present. Then you'd need to reopen the request for new data. http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=ajax-poller

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript [setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to regularly call a function. This function should then call one of [jQuery's AJAX Functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax), for example [$.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback).

Comment: i already have the ajax and settimeout functions, means that i have the new feeds content to be added, so what i'm looking for is the effect and function to add new divs with scrolling effect!