# Jquery scroll down effect for a newsfeed similar to Google's Realtime search feed or twitter news feed

Tags: jquery, animation

I like the scrolling effect seen in Google's Realtime search and the Twitter newsfeed.  I'm thinking jquery animation could be used...not really sure what the logic would be to create the push animation when a new result is available.  Anyone know of any jquery snippets / demo's that duplicate this effect?  Any plugins available anywhere? Or any ideas of how the animation would be reverse engineered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I needed:

Jquery slidedown effect
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown

and this stackoverflow question:
[How to make a real-time jquery effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087176/how-to-make-a-real-time-jquery-effect)